# "rails s" command is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server, rake

I am using Rails 4.2
On running command 
`rails s` or `rails server` 
terminal says:

```
_rails_command:2: permission denied: bin/rails
```

but

```
bundle exec rails s
```

is working. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: check executable permissions  `ls -l bin/rails` there should be `x` for your user/group

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env ruby<br>
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application', __FILE__)<br>
require_relative '../config/boot'<br>
require 'rails/commands'

Comment: then use it with `bundle exec`. It won't hurt :) !!

Comment: @ManishShrivastava will it affect heroku deployment ?

Comment: No, It won't affact Heroku deployement @AnshulGarg. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support

Comment: @AnshulGarg, even it's good practice to use bundle exec

Comment: sort advice - use `Ctrl+r` to write command again on terminal. you don't have to type complete command

Comment: @ManishShrivastava that's cool, I didn't know that.
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command did the job:

```
bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created your Rails project, when inside it, try running `bin/rails s`

Comment: permission denied: bin/rails

Answer (score 0):

Please check the executable permissions. Oleg asked for permissions, not the content.

This might be completely unrelated but do you have a `spring` file in the `bin` folder?

Comment: How do I check permissions? 
Yes, I have a spring file in the bin folder.

Comment: `ls -l <path of file>`
Also add 
`begin
  load File.expand_path("../spring", __FILE__)
rescue LoadError
end`
after `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` in the `bin/rails` file

Comment: No, I am using "bundle exec rails s" instead of "rails s"
This problem is with that app only, others are working fine.

Comment: This command did the job: bundle exec spring binstub --all

@frugalcoder